# Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-performance, sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have two SQL Servers on two different machines somewhere in the cloud (maybe Azure).

One is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU10) (KB4025925) - 11.0.6607.3 (X64)
Jul  8 2017 16:43:40
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

On this server there is a link to the second server.

The second server (`aae-sqldw-02`) is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU15-GDR) (KB4505221) - 13.0.4604.0 (X64)
Jun 15 2019 07:56:34
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

On the first server we are running a "simple" query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[LocalTable]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[LocalTable]
    ([DatabaseName]
    ,[SalesContractNumber]
    ,... 60 columns
    )
SELECT
    convert(varchar(128), DatabaseName) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
    ,convert(varchar(60), SalesContractNumber) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
    ,... 60 columns
FROM [aae-sqldw-02].[Fin_DWH].[dbo].[RemoteView]
WHERE DatabaseName = 'somename'
```

This query sometimes fails with an error:

```
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "aae-sqldw-02".
```

or with this error:

```
Cannot fetch the rowset from OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "aae-sqldw-02". .
```

I know that the second server is under a very heavy load most of the day. It literally maxes out its disk IO (255MB/sec). The brute-force solution is to simply move it to a more expensive plan with more IO. This change needs a lot of bureaucracy and will take a long time. Besides, there is no guarantee that the next tier will be enough.

[image: server load]

**Is there anything I can do with the given resources right now?**

When a query completes successfully, it can take between 1-3 hours. The query returns about 3M rows, about 4GB of data, so not too much.

When a query fails with `Cannot fetch a row`, last few times it failed after 9294 seconds (2.5 hours), 12326 seconds (3.5 hours).

When a query fails with `Cannot fetch the rowset`, it failed after 606 seconds, 611 seconds.

So, 600 seconds suggest some default 10min timeout (for connection?)
In those cases when connection succeeded, it started fetching the data, but failed in the process. Maybe the linked server could not send the next row fast enough and some other timeout kicked in.

When a query succeeded, it took 3841 seconds last time.

Here are the settings for the linked server:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'aae-sqldw-02', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'aae-sqldw-02',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'aae-sqldw-02', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
```

What do you think, would it make any difference if I explicitly set the `query timeout` option to something like 5 hours? Can it make things worse?

Obviously, the proper fix would be to look at what is going on at the server and optimize the queries to reduce the overall load, but is there anything I can do at a higher server / database level, so that the query completes, even if it takes a really long time?

We need to run this query once a week and right now we have to retry it several times until it completes successfully.

Comment: Could you provide the **execution plan** for the query you're trying to run?...the **collates** are suspect to causing potential **cardinality estimate** issues. If you guys are looking to upgrading your disk, if possible, aim for an NVMe. I've seen them improve IO bottlenecks almost 10-fold compared to a regular SSD.

Comment: @J.D. unfortunately, I could not get an estimated execution plan (because actual would take hours and I can't actually run this query in the middle of the week - it changes live data). I got this error in SSMS when trying to get an estimated execution plan: `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.` Apparently, there are some permissions lacking for this operation across linked server. I will look into optimizing the query, but not as a first step. As for disks - this is not a physical computer. Azure throttles disk IO according to the plan. If we pay more they will give more IO.

Comment: @VladimarBaranov I think you meant the ***actual*** **execution plan** would take hours, the ***estimated*** should return almost immediately. Though the ***actual*** is generally more meaningful, at least the ***estimated*** could be a start. If unable to fix the permissions you could take the `SELECT` statement of your query, place it in the context of your remote server, and get the **execution plan** from there (though this isn't exactly one-to-one then). Even cloud hosts offer alternative disk builds, so a tier with an NVMe should be available to you in Azure. The IO will be a lot faster.

Comment: @J.D. I don't think that the query itself and its plan matters at this moment. I will look into optimising the query in the second phase, but for now I just want it to run reliably till completion even when the linked server is under heavy load. (I had a quick look, there is no obvious problem with the query itself that stands out.) My understanding is that the link between two servers is not reliable. Technically it is easy to add more IO - just pay more. The limitation is not the hardware, the limitation is artificial by the cloud service provider.

Comment: @J.D. Do you have any ideas what settings I could tweak on each server to reduce the chances of query failing with `Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider`? In any case, in the end we'll need to transfer ~4GB of data across the network between the two servers. Is there anything I can do at the server/database level to make this transfer more reliable?

Comment: I understand the IO *limitation is artificial* by the cloud provider, I've worked in **AWS** which operates in a similar manner. I'm saying you'll get more IO for your money spent on Azure by looking into one of their tiers with NVMes if your bottleneck currently is IO. The *artificial limitation* is a constant on any tier you choose so that's moot, but NVMes offer a lot more IO than SSDs and therefore when you pay for a tier with an NVMe your money is going to the direct improvement of IO (per Azure's control) rather than other tiers where some of the money is going...

Comment: ...towards some IO improvement but you may also be paying for improved memory or CPU as well, which you don't actually need. So it's more monetarily efficient to look at their disk focussed plans which should contain NVMes. Outside of that, without optimizing the query, I'm not sure what else you can do. I'm not aware of any database settings you can tune to improve the *reliability* as I've never even heard of that being an issue with a linked server, even for queries running for hours, and my intuition tells me your issue lies elsewhere, perhaps warranting a call with Azure's support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, I think this [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) might be what you're looking for, except I have a feeling this is only applicable to an on-prem instance and you won't be able to adjust this in Azure.

I've also found a tangentially related [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46719292/5059085) where the accepted answer was to increase the **DTUs** for a highly intensive **IO** workload, even if you just temporarily scaled up to run that query and scaled back down when it was done. (Again scaling up to an NVMe based tier might payoff momentously here.)

Unfortunately the errors you're receiving don't have a lot of concrete information out there, and have quite varying causes. The only one that I found that *might* be relevant to your case is this [StackExchange post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19759/150011) where the issue was due to deadlocks happening across the linked server. Perhaps you're running into the same issue? (Which theoretically could be a timing thing resulting from your server crawling for other concurrently running queries when the **IO** is maxed out.)

Outside of that, the only other option I think you have is tuning the query itself to improve performance. Even being throttled at ~250 MB/s of IO here, 4 GB of data should be processed in about 16 seconds + whatever bottleneck might be added for the network latency. But 1+ hours definitely seems off, even for 3 million rows (deadlocks seeming more suspect perhaps). For the error you're getting which isn't directly a **timeout** error itself, I would consider talking to an Azure rep to see if there's more to your underlying issue.